# Copying an array from host to constant memory

Tags: cuda

I'm trying to copy an array of 9 floats from Host to constant memory. 
I declared first a constant array in the header file:

```
    Header.h:
#ifndef __FUNCTIONS_H__
#define __FUNCTIONS_H__

void CudaKernelWrapper(     int sample_indices_list_size,
                            int *gpu_sample_indices,//size:2*Warp_size * Number_multiprocessors=sample_indices_list_size
                            int localIterationCount,
                            float * _pts0_d,
                            float *_pts1_d);
 __constant__ float K1_d[9];
 __constant__ float K2_d[9];

#endif
```

In my main file,  arrays `K1_h[9]`and `K2_h[9]` are loaded from a text file.

```
main.cpp:

#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <helper_cuda.h>
#include "Header.h"

#define PARAMS_REQUIRED 5
#define DATA_PT_SIZE 4
#define HYPOTHESIS_SIZE 9

#define localIterationCount 32

extern "C" void ReadData(
    int nmatches,
    float *pts0_h,
    float *pts1_h
   );

extern "C" void LoadParameters(float* K1_h, float *K2_h);


// Main program

void main(int argc, const char **argv){



float *pts0_h, *pts1_h, *pts0_d,*pts1_d;
int nmatches=1437,i;
float K1_h[9], K2_h[9];

 /*Allocate memory*/

  pts0_h=(float*)malloc(nmatches*2*sizeof(float));
  pts1_h=(float*)malloc(nmatches*2*sizeof(float));

  /*Read Data from text Files*/

  ReadData(nmatches, pts0_h,pts1_h);

  /*allocate memory for data on device*/
  checkCudaErrors( cudaMalloc((void **)&pts0_d, sizeof(float)*2*nmatches));
  checkCudaErrors( cudaMalloc((void **)&pts1_d, sizeof(float)*2*nmatches));

  int sample_indices_list_size=160;
  int *sample_indices_list; 
  int *gpu_sample_indices;

  sample_indices_list = (int*)malloc(sample_indices_list_size*sizeof(int));
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(&gpu_sample_indices, sample_indices_list_size*sizeof(int)));

  //Random indices

  for( i=0; i < sample_indices_list_size; i++) {
        sample_indices_list[i] = (int)(nmatches * (rand()/(1.0 + RAND_MAX)));
        }

  //Normalization Parameters
     LoadParameters(K1_h, K2_h);

 //Copy normalization parameters to constant memory
      checkCudaErrors( cudaMemcpyToSymbol (  K1_d, K1_h,  sizeof(float)*9));
      checkCudaErrors( cudaMemcpyToSymbol (  K2_d,  K2_h, sizeof(float)*9));

      //Copy data to device
      checkCudaErrors( cudaMemcpy(pts0_d, pts0_h, sizeof(float)*2*nmatches,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
      checkCudaErrors( cudaMemcpy(pts1_d, pts1_h, sizeof(float)*2*nmatches,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
      checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(gpu_sample_indices, sample_indices_list,sizeof(int)*sample_indices_list_size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

       //Launch kernel with a wrapper function

      CudaKernelWrapper( sample_indices_list_size,
                       gpu_sample_indices,
                       localIterationCount,
                       pts0_d,
                       pts1_d);


      getLastCudaError("GPU_Kernel failed\n");

       free(pts0_h);
       free(pts1_h);
       free(sample_indices_list);

       checkCudaErrors( cudaFree(pts0_d) );
       checkCudaErrors( cudaFree(pts1_d) );
       checkCudaErrors( cudaFree(gpu_sample_indices));

}
```

And the kernel file.

```
kernel.cu:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <helper_cuda.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include "Header.h"

#define PARAMS_REQUIRED 5
#define DATA_PT_SIZE 4

__device__ void Normalization (float *src, float *src_norm);



__global__ void CUDA_Estimation_Kernel
                                       (int sample_indices_list_size,
                                        int *gpu_sample_indices,
                                        int localIterationCount,
                                        float  *_pts0_d,
                                        float  *_pts1_d)

{   int i;
    int rand_idx[PARAMS_REQUIRED];
    float _src[PARAMS_REQUIRED*DATA_PT_SIZE];
    float _src_norm[PARAMS_REQUIRED*DATA_PT_SIZE];
    const int idx = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;


    if(idx >= localIterationCount) { 
        return;
    }

    #pragma unroll
        for (i=0; i<PARAMS_REQUIRED; ++i)
        {
            rand_idx[i] = gpu_sample_indices[idx*PARAMS_REQUIRED + i];

        }



    for (i=0; i < PARAMS_REQUIRED; i++) {

             _src[DATA_PT_SIZE*i+0]=_pts0_d[(DATA_PT_SIZE/2)*rand_idx[i]+0];
             _src[DATA_PT_SIZE*i+1]=_pts0_d[(DATA_PT_SIZE/2)*rand_idx[i]+1];
             _src[DATA_PT_SIZE*i+2]=_pts1_d[(DATA_PT_SIZE/2)*rand_idx[i]+0];
             _src[DATA_PT_SIZE*i+3]=_pts1_d[(DATA_PT_SIZE/2)*rand_idx[i]+1];
        }

    Normalization (_src, _src_norm);

}

__device__ void Normalization (float *src, float *src_norm)
{   int i;
    for(i=0;i<17;i+=4)
    { src_norm[i]=  K1_d[0]*src[i]+K1_d[1]*src[i+1]+K1_d[2];
      src_norm[i+1]=K1_d[3]*src[i]+K1_d[4]*src[i+1]+K1_d[5];
      src_norm[i+2]=K2_d[0]*src[i+2]+K2_d[1]*src[i+3]+K2_d[2];
      src_norm[i+3]=K2_d[3]*src[i+2]+K2_d[4]*src[i+3]+K2_d[5];
    }

}


//wrapper

void CudaKernelWrapper(int sample_indices_list_size,
                       int *gpu_sample_indices,
                       int localIterationCount,
                       float * _pts0_d,
                       float *_pts1_d)



{   CUDA_Estimation_Kernel <<<1,32>>> ( sample_indices_list_size,
                                      gpu_sample_indices,
                                      localIterationCount,
                                       _pts0_d,
                                       _pts1_d);





  cudaDeviceSynchronize();

}
```

The compilation was successful but when running the code the following error appears:

```
CUDA error at c:\users\xxx\main.cpp:265 code=13(cudaErrorInvalidSymbol) "cudaMemcpyToSymbol ( K1d_inv, K1_inv, sizeof(float)*9)"
```

From the answers of other similar questions, I tried:

```
checkCudaErrors( cudaMemcpyToSymbol (  "K1_d",  K1_h, sizeof(float)*9, 0, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
```

but always the same error.
How to copy a 1D array from host to constant memory?

Comment: Without a concise and complete working example it will be impossible to say what is going wrong. Please edit that into your question

Comment: Because the code is too large, I rewrote an example similar in general to the original code, illustrating how I used the constant memory in my code

Comment: My main file is a cpp file and not a cu file like in the cuda SDK examples, I couldn't find a way how to write to constant memory from my main function,  (cpp file)..I have to change my main from cpp to cu then?

Comment: That's correct.  You cannot use CUDA syntax (e.g. `__constant__`) in a .cpp file.  Therefore I think your statement that "The compilation was successful" could not possibly be true, since you include `Header.h` in `main.cpp`.  But even if you change main.cpp to main.cu, it will not fix the problem I mentioned above.   You need to move the kernel, the `__constant__` *definition* and the `cudaMemcpyToSymbol` statements into the same compilation unit, i.e. the same file.  You probably shouldn't put *any* of these 3 items in a header file.